# Number $n$ such that $2^n+3^n$ has exactly $23$ prime divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, divisibility

Can anyone help me prove this question? Thank you.

> Prove that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that the number $2^n+3^n$ has exactly $23$ prime divisors.

(I have thought about some fomulas about $\omega (n)$, like ${\displaystyle \sum _{d\mid n}|\mu (d)|=2^{\omega (n)}}$, or construct the sequence ${n_k}$ such that $2^{n_{k+1}}+3^{n_{k+1}}$ has exactly one more prime divisor than $2^{n_{k}}+3^{n_{k}}$, but it seems to be hard.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does n have to be integer or whole number or can it just be rational? In which case, this is trivial.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your comment. I have fixed the post.

Comment: @stuartstevenson n is positive interger.

Comment: Good question. I cannot solve it, but I found that $2^{3^k}+3^{3^k}$ has more than $k$ prime divisors. Quick proof:
Use induction. $2^{3^{k+1}}+3^{3^{k+1}}=(2^{3^k}+3^{3^k})(2^{3^{2k}}-2^{3^k}3^{3^k}+3^{3^{2k}})$ and easy calculation shows that $2^{3^k}+3^{3^k}$ and $2^{3^{2k}}-2^{3^k}3^{3^k}+3^{3^{2k}}$ are coprime.

Comment: I wish "23" were "13", as then I could just say "Observe $2^{150}+3^{150}=13\cdot61\cdot2341\cdot4621\cdot4801\cdot11701\cdot24001\cdot797701\cdot9802501\cdot104189401\cdot1333073701\cdot2296284901\cdot12826646101$.".

Comment: @MarkS. I think 23 is a "special" number, but I don't know why

Comment: Btw there is a [examples-counterexamples] tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proof by example:

$$2^{342}+3^{342}$$

Factors into exactly $23$ distinct prime factors:

$$ 13, 37, 61, 73, 181, 229, 2053, 8209, 13681, 15277, 25309, 102829, 30883969, 196498153, 724174057, 743780461, 2117021041, 2230888573, 54458107801, 8077765456081, 80381675102807053, 103911691734684541, 324469548901114381 $$

Comment: How did you find this factorization?

Comment: @lhf I was spending $10$ seconds at most factoring a single $2^n+3^n$ expression (discarding the case if a single factor wasn't found in that time frame), for all $n$ until an example was found, in Wolfram Mathematica.